# An elementary error in Principia Mathematica?

Tags: logic, well-orders

This is a quote from page 1, volume III of Principia Mathematica, by Whitehead and Russell: "A 'well-ordered' series is one which is such that every existent class contained in it has a first term, or, what comes to the same thing, one which is such that every class which has successors has a sequent." The second part of that sentence seems to imply, in modern terminology, that a (linearly ordered) set *A*'s being well-ordered is equivalent to: for every non-empty subset *B* of *A* such that *B* has an upper bound in *A* not in *B*, there exists in *A* an element *a* such that *a* is the next element in *A* after *B*, i.e., that if there exists a *c* in *A* such that *c* is greater than every *d* in *B*, then there exists an *a* in *A* such that *a* is greater than every *e* in *B*, and there does not exist an *f* in *A* such that *f* is greater than every *g* in *B* and *a* is greater than *f*. (Sorry if that was excessively tedious) An obvious counter-example to this statement of *PM* is Z, the positive and negative integers and zero. Z is such that for every non-empty subset *B* of Z which has an upper bound in Z not in *B*, there exists in Z a next element after *B*, but Z is not well-ordered, since Z is a non-empty subset of Z which has no first term.
Link to PM v III: https://quod.lib.umich.edu/u/umhistmath/aat3201.0003.001/2?page=root;rgn=works;size=100;view=pdf;rgn1=title;q1=Principia+Mathematica

Is my interpretation of the terminology of *PM* correct, and if so, is this elementary error in *PM* well-known, and what do mathematicians and logicians think of it?

Comment: There is no error, the principia specifically mentions series, where as you mention the set Z as a counter example, here lies your mistake, Z is not a sequence, but a set. A set is not an ordered collection while a sequence( and its sum which is the series)is.  If you want to prove leibniz wrong, you would need to provide a counter example using his exact definitions of series.

Comment: @dvd280: On the other hand, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell-Whitehead#Part_V_Series._Volume_II_%E2%9C%B8200_to_%E2%9C%B8234_and_volume_III_%E2%9C%B8250_to_%E2%9C%B8276) “series” is PM's term for what we call a totally ordered set. And $\mathbb Z$ definitely is a totally ordered set. I don't have access to PM itself to check the claim of Wikipedia.

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}$, $\varnothing$ has successors (every integer is an upper bound), but not a smallest one.

Comment: @dvd280 Why do you mention Leibniz?

Comment: @Kruckman Its been a long day xD

Answer (score 1):

What is said in the introduction is true.
In Principia the concept of "sequent" of a class A for a relation P is quite "general" and abstract.
To simplify a bit, if P is a series and A a class that isn't empty and it is included in the field of P (the field is just the union of the domain and co-domain of P) than the sequent of A for P (if any) is the "first" term in the series P that comes after all the elements of A.
But, if the class A is empty than the sequent of A, if any, is the first term of the series P.
You can easily find the "justification" of my claims by looking at Principia chapter *206 (especially *206.14 and *206.12).
Your counter-example doesn't work simply because the null class, in the series of integers for magnitude, doesn't have a sequent.
As a matter of fact in *250 it is proved what is claimed in the introduction of the chapter (see *250.122).

Comment: You are correct. In the modern definition of "well-ordered set", in the quoted PM introduction's definition, and in my paraphrase of PM's "what comes to the same thing" equivalent of that definition, the requirement of having a smallest element is made only for non-empty ("existent" in PM, meaning, I think, non-empty) sets. However, my paraphrase was wrong; PM's equivalent "what comes..." doesn't restrict its requirement, that every subset which has a succesor has a sequent, to non-empty subsets. The empty subset of Z has a successor, bu no sequent, so Z isn't a counterexample. I was careless.